# pageupdates/add returns invalid JSON

Tags: api, foursquare

I am assuming this is an appropriate forum for reporting issues too. Apologies if not.

The pageupdates/add end point is returning an invalid JSON response. There is a duplicate "likes" key. See response.pageUpdate in snipped response below.

```
{
"meta": {
      "code": 200
},
"notifications": [
    {
        "type": "notificationTray",
        "item": {
            "unreadCount": 0
        }
    }
],
"response": {
    "pageUpdate": {
        "id": "xxx",
        "createdAt": 1348875498,
        "page": {
        },
        "shout": "...",
        "entities": [
        ],
        "photos": {
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "groups": [

            ]
        },
        "canonicalUrl": "...",
        "venues": {
        },
        "venueGroups": {
        },
        "deliveryCount": 0,
        "scopeSize": 1,
        "creator": {
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 0,
            "groups": [

            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, James. We will investigate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report, James. We've fixed this problem, and the duplicate likes entry should stop appearing with our next deploy.